# Sankey chart is not displayed in RStudio Viewer using networkD3 in R

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, htmlwidgets, networkd3

Based on the example below:

```
# Load package
library(networkD3)

# Load energy projection data
URL <- "https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/master/JSONdata/energy.json"
Energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)


# Now we have 2 data frames: a 'links' data frame with 3 columns (from, to, value), and a 'nodes' data frame that gives the name of each node.
head( Energy$links )
head( Energy$nodes )

# Thus we can plot it
p <- sankeyNetwork(Links = Energy$links, Nodes = Energy$nodes, Source = "source",
              Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              units = "TWh", fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)
p
```

I do not underastand how the indexing in this example happens since there is no connection between the `nodes` `name` and the indexes (`source` and `target` of the `links` dataframe). Also how does this `0` is explained since `source` and `target` are indexes?

I have tried to create my own sankey chart with:

```
name<-c("J","B","A")
nodes3<-data.frame(name)
source<-c("B","B","J")
target<-c("A","A","B")
value<-c(5,6,7)
links3<-data.frame(source,target,value)

p <- sankeyNetwork(Links = data.frame(links3), Nodes = data.frame(nodes3), Source = "source",
                   Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
                   units = "cases", fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)
p
```

But while everything seems to run I get no plot in RStudio Viewer and no error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `source` and `target` columns/variables in the `links` data frame should be numeric, where each value is the index (0-indexed, not 1-indexed as usual in R) of the node it refers to in the `nodes` data frame.

So for instance, in the first example...

```r
head(Energy$links)
#>   source target   value
#> 1      0      1 124.729
#> 2      1      2   0.597
#> 3      1      3  26.862
#> 4      1      4 280.322
#> 5      1      5  81.144
#> 6      6      2  35.000

head(Energy$nodes)
#>                   name
#> 1 Agricultural 'waste'
#> 2       Bio-conversion
#> 3               Liquid
#> 4               Losses
#> 5                Solid
#> 6                  Gas
```

the first link goes from 0 (row 0 of the `nodes` data frame which is the node named "Agricultural 'waste'") to 1 (row 1 of the `nodes` data frame which is the node named "Bio-conversion")

So for the second example, you could achieve that with...

```r
name<-c("J","B","A")
nodes3<-data.frame(name)
source<-c("B","B","J")
target<-c("A","A","B")
value<-c(5,6,7)
links3<-data.frame(source,target,value)



links3$source_id <- match(links3$source, nodes3$name) - 1
links3$target_id <- match(links3$target, nodes3$name) - 1

library(networkD3)

sankeyNetwork(Links = links3, Nodes = nodes3, 
          Source = "source_id", Target = "target_id", Value = "value", 
          NodeID = "name", units = "cases", fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)
```

[image]